# Como implementar um mecanismo de busca em um site que está em um ambiente Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Fiz um site no ambiente Node.js, usando Express, template engine Jade, O problema é que o mecanismo de busca (search engine) que eu tenho pronto é em PHP, não sei se posso rodá-lo em ambiente Node; se puder como faria?

Se não for possível, ou se souber como eu posso fazer um mecanismo de pesquisa direto no ambiente Node, peço-lhes essa ajuda.

Comment: Onde estão os dados?

Comment: Dois indicadores sobre os quais tenho ouvido falar: __Solr__: http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/, __Elastic search__: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html

Comment: Valeu Sergio, vou analisar esses api. Encontrei um plugin Jquery que faz pesquisa em modo static, live e de image , estou implementando para ver se o resultado vai satisfazer. site do plugin: http://www.tipue.com/search/

Comment: @ThiagoJem, responda à pergunta do bfavaretto, a pergunta como está não é bem clara e mais completa pode ser bem útil a outros no futuro.

Comment: @bfavaretto os dados são os enormes arquivos em PHP. Estava pensando em mecanismo de busca apenas em PHP, graças a Deus lembrei de pesquisar outras formas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanto o Solr como o ElasticSearch funcionam com base em APIs REST, você instala os mesmos no seu ambiente e envia requests para as APIs para obter os resultados em JSON, XML ou qualquer outro formato.

Tanto o Solr como o ElasticSearch possuem clients em Node:

[Solr client em NodeJS](http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/)

[ElasticSearch client em NodeJS](https://github.com/phillro/node-elasticsearch-client)

Isso evita que vc tenha que fazer os requests e tratar os responses manualmente.

Comment: Qual dos dois você acha que é melhor para pesquisa de páginas no site (Para pesquisar textos, que estão inseridos nas páginas, e os internautas achar o conteúdo que deseja com facilidade.).
Eu implementei o freefind que é "terceirizado", fácil de adicionar, apenas copiar e colar a marcação no HTML, Css e o JavaScript, indexação automática, muitas opções de pesquisas e possibilita a visualização das palavras mais pesquisadas

Comment: ... 3 mil páginas podem ser indexadas gratuitamente, o único problema é que tem anúncios na versão gratuita.
No entanto, estou estudando e assim que souber vou estar implementando um motor de busca "próprio" em meu site,Sei que não vai ficar tão completo como o freefind, mais pelo menos vou ter maior controle e não vai ter anúncios.

Link do Freefind: http://www.freefind.com/